# Adding New Column In Hive using DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have one temporary table(daily truncate and load) in which i m loading data from one csv file using load statement the table,storing data in the form of textfile in table.Now in this table i need to create one column which can capture current date.For that I'm Creating one Df from that table and using withcolumn method adding new column and again saving this df in the same table using mode("overwrite").But when I'm Checking data into my table not getting any data.can anyone please suggest how should i implement this.I've tried below code.

```
    CREATE TABLE test (id String, Name STRING,college STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFile;
    load Data inpath 'path' into table dbname.test ;
    val s1=spark.sql("select * from dbname.test")
    val s2=s1.withColumn("Admission_date", date_add(current_date(),0));
    s2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("dbname.test")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are **`reading and overwriting`** the same table.

- But in spark we need to do some workarounds.

**`Steps:`**

```
//1.read hive table
val s1=spark.sql("select * from dbname.test")
val s2=s1.withColumn("Admission_date", date_add(current_date(),0));

//2.write into temporary table tmp
s2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("dbname.tmp")

//3.read from temporary table and overwrite final table
val s3=spark.sql("select * from dbname.tmp")
s2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("dbname.test")

//4.drop the temporary table
spark.sql("drop table dbname.tmp")
```

Comment: when I'm loading the data from temp table to my table using s2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("dbname.test").It is also changing my table properties
from text to parquet.
so first time after loading data when I'm again loading data into same table after truncate using load statement it's showing 'file.csv'
  is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [65, 65, 10, 10]    before:
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
after:
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'